# What is the meanning of these messages I get while installing virtualbox on openSUSE?

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox

I ran `sudo zypper install virtualbox` to install virtualbox on openSUSE 15.5.

I got the following output:

```
Retrieving repository 'Update repository of openSUSE Backports' metadata ...................................................................................................[done]
Building repository 'Update repository of openSUSE Backports' cache ........................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'Update repository with updates from SUSE Linux Enterprise 15' metadata ..............................................................................[done]
Building repository 'Update repository with updates from SUSE Linux Enterprise 15' cache ...................................................................................[done]
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

The following recommended package was automatically selected:
  virtualbox-qt

The following 3 NEW packages are going to be installed:
  virtualbox virtualbox-kmp-default virtualbox-qt

3 new packages to install.
Overall download size: 42.0 MiB. Already cached: 0 B. After the operation, additional 108.8 MiB will be used.
Continue? [y/n/v/...? shows all options] (y): y
Retrieving: virtualbox-kmp-default-7.0.12_k5.14.21_150500.55.31-lp155.2.13.1.x86_64 (Main Update Repository)                                                  (1/3), 618.1 KiB
Retrieving: virtualbox-kmp-default-7.0.12_k5.14.21_150500.55.31-lp155.2.13.1.x86_64.rpm ......................................................................[done (875.4 KiB/s)]
Retrieving: virtualbox-7.0.12-lp155.2.13.1.x86_64 (Main Update Repository)                                                                                    (2/3),  37.9 MiB
Retrieving: virtualbox-7.0.12-lp155.2.13.1.x86_64.rpm .........................................................................................................[done (24.8 MiB/s)]
Retrieving: virtualbox-qt-7.0.12-lp155.2.13.1.x86_64 (Main Update Repository)                                                                                 (3/3),   3.4 MiB
Retrieving: virtualbox-qt-7.0.12-lp155.2.13.1.x86_64.rpm ......................................................................................................[done (10.3 MiB/s)]

Checking for file conflicts: ...............................................................................................................................................[done]
(1/3) Installing: virtualbox-kmp-default-7.0.12_k5.14.21_150500.55.31-lp155.2.13.1.x86_64 ..................................................................................[done]
/usr/sbin/groupadd -r vboxusers
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxNetNAT to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0755) 
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxNetDHCP to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0755)
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxNetAdpCtl to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0755)
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxHeadless to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0755)
(2/3) Installing: virtualbox-7.0.12-lp155.2.13.1.x86_64 ....................................................................................................................[done]
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBoxVM to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0750)
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxSDL to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0755)
(3/3) Installing: virtualbox-qt-7.0.12-lp155.2.13.1.x86_64 .................................................................................................................[done]
Running post-transaction scripts ...........................................................................................................................................[done]
```

Can anyone, please, explain the messages:

```
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxNetNAT to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0755) 
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxNetDHCP to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0755)
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxNetAdpCtl to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0755)
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxHeadless to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0755)
```

and

```
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBoxVM to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0750)
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxSDL to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0755)
```

Did something go wrong? Must I  fix the permissions of those files in some way?

Thank you!

Comment: They were wrong, the install fixed it. By the looks the permissions were updated via a postinstall script. Nothing to worry about.